# Typeface.createFromAsset NullPointerException - only sometimes

Tags: android, assets, android-inflate

In my starting activity, I call `FontFactory.init(getApplicationContext());` to set Context to FontFactory class.

I have also class which extends `TextView` and in constructor of this TextView there is `setTypeface(FontFactory.Fonts.ROBOTO_LIGHT.getFont());`.  So a font from file is loaded when first needed, not before, during startup.

Problem is that **only sometimes, not every time** there is a **startup error** and application crashes:

> InflateException: Binary XML file line .. - error inflating class LayoutWithExtendedTextView
>
> Caused by NullPointerException in Typeface nativeCreateFromAsset, createFRomAsset and FontFactory.loadFont(FontFactory.java:46)

Line 46 is `return Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager, fontEnum.getPath());`

My FontFactory class:

```
public final class FontFactory {

    public enum Fonts {
        ROBOTO_CONDENSED("fonts/Roboto-Condensed.ttf"), ROBOTO_LIGHT(
                "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf"), ROBOTO_MEDIUM(
                "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf"), ROBOTO_REGULAR(
                "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");

        private String path;
        private Typeface loadedFont = null;

        private Fonts(String path) {
            this.path = path;
        }

        public String getPath() {
            return path;
        }

        public void setLoadedFont(Typeface font) {
            this.loadedFont = font;
        }

        public Typeface getFont() {
            if (loadedFont == null) {
                this.loadedFont = FontFactory.loadFont(this);
            }
            return loadedFont;
        }
    }

    private static final String TAG = "FontFactory";
    private static AssetManager assetManager;

    public static void init(Context context) {
        assetManager = context.getAssets();
    }

    private static Typeface loadFont(FontFactory.Fonts fontEnum) {
        return Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager, fontEnum.getPath());
    }
}
```

Is there some delay when loading asset?

Thank you.

Comment: make sure u are calling `init` method to initialize context  and assetManager before calling `loadFont` method ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't .

Answer (score 1):

metrhod **createFromAsset** calls **nativeCreateFromAsset** which is native C++ code.

```
static JNINativeMethod gTypefaceMethods[] = {
{ "nativeCreate",        "(Ljava/lang/String;I)I", (void*)Typeface_create },
{ "nativeCreateFromTypeface", "(II)I", (void*)Typeface_createFromTypeface },
{ "nativeUnref",              "(I)V",  (void*)Typeface_unref },
{ "nativeGetStyle",           "(I)I",  (void*)Typeface_getStyle },
{ "nativeCreateFromAsset",    "(Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;Ljava/lang/String;)I",
                                       (void*)Typeface_createFromAsset },
{ "nativeCreateFromFile",     "(Ljava/lang/String;)I",
                                       (void*)Typeface_createFromFile }
};
```

Digging through the code, I found the following implementation of **Typeface_createFromAsset**.

```
static SkTypeface* Typeface_createFromAsset(JNIEnv* env, jobject,
                                        jobject jassetMgr,
                                        jstring jpath) {

NPE_CHECK_RETURN_ZERO(env, jassetMgr);
NPE_CHECK_RETURN_ZERO(env, jpath);

AssetManager* mgr = assetManagerForJavaObject(env, jassetMgr);
if (NULL == mgr) {
    return NULL;
}

AutoJavaStringToUTF8    str(env, jpath);
Asset* asset = mgr->open(str.c_str(), Asset::ACCESS_BUFFER);
if (NULL == asset) {
    return NULL;
}

return SkTypeface::CreateFromStream(new AssetStream(asset, true));
}
```

This method returns null in the following two circumstances:

- First, the asset manager provided is null
- Second, it was unable to create load the asset from the file system.

Also, read question [“Native typeface cannot be made” only for some people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766930/native-typeface-cannot-be-made-only-for-some-people/) which provides probably the most complete information regarding the issue (not worth copy/pasting here)