# Issue with Custom Fonts

Tags: android

I noticed this question in the forum many times but no solid solution. My issue is slightly different though. I have a sample application which does the following:

```
    TextView textViewBold=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textBold);
    textViewBold.setText("Hello World Bold Font!!!!");
    Typeface typeFaceBold=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/xyz_bold.ttf");
    typeFaceBold.setTypeface(typeFaceBold);
```

This works brilliantly!!!!. I use the same code in my project which uses lots of images and is slightly bigger and i get the "**native typeface cannot be made error**". I tried the work around solution as posted here ["Native typeface cannot be made" only for some people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766930/native-typeface-cannot-be-made-only-for-some-people) i still get the same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.