# Access a typeface once from asset and use it as a reference

Tags: android

I am trying to create a method that returns titleFont and contentFont typeface so that it would improve efficiency by just returning reference and reduce length of code. I know its easy but I am not getting the way. Can anyone help please. or any alternatives would be appreciated.. Sorry for bad english

Here is the method that will be running several times..

```
protected void onPostExecute(Article result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    TextView txtTitle= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    txtTitle.setTypeface(titleFont);
    txtTitle.setText(result.getTitle());

    private Typeface titleFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/InterstateCondMonoLgt.ttf");
    private Typeface contentFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/InterstateLight.ttf");

    TextView txtMain= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.main);
    txtMain.setTypeface(contentFont);
    txtMain.setText(result.getContent());
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope this help you ;)

**FontUtil class**

```
public class FontUtil {

    private static Typeface mTitleFont;
    private static Typeface mContentFont;

    public static enum FontType {

        TITLE_FONT {
            public String toString() {
                return "fonts/InterstateCondMonoLgt.ttf";
            }
        },

        CONTENT_FONT {
            public String toString() {
                return "fonts/InterstateLight.ttf";
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return Typeface Instance with the font passed as parameter
     */
    public static Typeface getTypeface(Context context, String typefaceName) {
        Typeface typeFace = null;

        try {
            if (typefaceName.equals(FontType.TITLE_FONT.toString())) {
                if (mTitleFont == null) {
                    mTitleFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), typefaceName);
                }
                typeFace = mTitleFont;
            } else if (typefaceName.equals(FontType.CONTENT_FONT.toString())) {
                if (mContentFont == null) {
                    mContentFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), typefaceName);
                }
                typeFace = mContentFont;
            } 
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            typeFace = Typeface.DEFAULT;
        }

        return typeFace;
    }

    /**
     * @return Typeface Instance with the font passed as parameter
     */
    public static Typeface getTypeface(Context context, FontType typefaceName) {
        return getTypeface(context, typefaceName.toString());
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
protected void onPostExecute(Article result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    TextView txtTitle= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    txtTitle.setTypeface( FontUtil.getTypeface(mContext, FontType.TITLE_FONT) );
    txtTitle.setText(result.getTitle());

    TextView txtMain= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.main);
    txtMain.setTypeface( FontUtil.getTypeface(mContext, FontType.CONTENT_FONT) );
    txtMain.setText(result.getContent());
}
```

Comment: I tired that answer, it throws out an exception: native typeface cannot be made. What needs to be done?

Comment: I have used that code a lot of times and it works like a charm. However, there is an Android bug reported that could be the reason of your issue (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9904). For more informaiton please visit this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766930/native-typeface-cannot-be-made-only-for-some-people

Comment: @DiegoPalomar, your logic works but "fonts/" is used twice. One is under enums, and the other one is under "getTypeface" method.
Since there are two of them, the font's path is like "assets/fonts/fonts/fontName.ttf". And it throws the native typeface exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can make one utility class in your project with

```
private Typeface titleFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/InterstateCondMonoLgt.ttf");
private Typeface contentFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/InterstateLight.ttf");
```

and then simply write geter for it like

```
public Typeface getTitleFont() {
    return titleFont;
}
```

or what I like more, if you have inherited classes you put in your base class like:

```
public static Typeface titleFont;
```

and then

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    titleFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/InterstateCondMonoLgt.ttf");
}
```

this way you will always have fonts
just call `textView.setTypeface(titleFont);` anywhere you need

Answer (score 0):

All the variables created inside a particular method is private on its own . **You cant give access modifiers to any variables declared inside a method**. It will give you compilation error.
I will suggest you to declare this typefaces variable as class level variable and initialize them inside the constructor of the ASYNCTASK. Otherwise every time your onPostExecute() will get called , every time it will create a typeface which may cause memory overhead at a later point of time.

Answer (score 0):

Create some util class and put all code there like :

```
public class Utils
{
    public static Typeface getTitleFont()
    {
        return Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),"fonts/InterstateCondMonoLgt.ttf");
    }
}
```

And use like this :

```
TextView txtMain= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.main);
txtMain.setTypeface(your_package.Utils.getTitleFont());
```

Comment: Looks fine but using this method TypeFace would be created each time I call the method... so its same as my solution..@Diago-Palomar 's solution just creates the typeface only once