# How to change font to default as defined in Xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, fonts

I have changed fonts of my Textviews  using the

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"fonts/Arial.ttf");
```

In my Xml layout i have many textviews with different fonts, i  want to retain this any time programmatically

Tried  the following

```
Typeface.DEFAULT
```

and   `Typeface font =null;`

All the textviews  are set to same font not the ones in Xml

How to retain the font without having to restart my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution could be using static instances of TypeFace class. Some time ago I proposed a solution to this problem in this thread: [**Access a typeface once from asset and use it as a reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847531/access-a-typeface-once-from-asset-and-use-it-as-a-reference/18847778#18847778). I hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1)create a class name as CustomTextView and copy paste this code but make sure that the custom font should be Project Assets folder. So you can replace font name.

package YOUR_PACKAGE;

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView{

    public CustomButton(Context context) {
        super( context );
        setFont();

    }

    public CustomTextView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super( context, attrs );
        setFont();
    }

    public CustomTextView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super( context, attrs, defStyle );
        setFont();
    }

    private void setFont() {
        Typeface normal = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/Arial.ttf");
        setTypeface( normal, Typeface.NORMAL );

    }
}
```

Step-2)

Use This custom TextView in your layout

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/signing_details"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100" >

<YOUR_PACKAGE.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="@string/app_name"
                 android:textSize="16sp" />
</ LinearLayout>
```

**You can also use this CustomTextView dynamically**

```
 CustomTextView textView = new CustomTextView (this);
 textView.setText(res.getString(R.string.app_name));
 textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
 textView.setTextSize(16);
```

Hope this help you.