# Changing font in android app crashes the application - native typeface cannot be made

Tags: android, fonts, android-typeface

I am trying to include a customized font in my android application. This is the tutorial that I followed and this seems to have worked for many people: http://tharindudassanayake.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/use-sinhala-fonts-for-your-android-app/

This is how I have tried it:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sinhala_font"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="wdhqfndajka"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sinhala_font);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/amal.TTF");
        txt.setTypeface(font);
```

Unfortunately app crashes (due to native typeface cannot be made) and I get the following in my log cat:

```
10-27 11:39:14.311: E/AndroidRuntime(28133): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 11:39:14.311: E/AndroidRuntime(28133): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sinhala/com.example.sinhala.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
10-27 11:39:14.311: E/AndroidRuntime(28133):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
10-27 11:39:14.311: E/AndroidRuntime(28133):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
10-27 11:39:14.311: E/AndroidRuntime(28133):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
10-27 11:39:14.311: E/AndroidRuntime(28133):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
10-27 11:39:14.311: E/AndroidRuntime(28133):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-27 11:39:14.311: E/AndroidRuntime(28133):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-27 11:39:14.311: E/AndroidRuntime(28133):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
10-27 11:39:14.311: E/AndroidRuntime(28133):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 11:39:14.311: E/AndroidRuntime(28133):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-27 11:39:14.311: E/AndroidRuntime(28133):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
10-27 11:39:14.311: E/AndroidRuntime(28133):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
10-27 11:39:14.311: E/AndroidRuntime(28133):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-27 11:39:14.311: E/AndroidRuntime(28133): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
10-27 11:39:14.311: E/AndroidRuntime(28133):    at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:238)
10-27 11:39:14.311: E/AndroidRuntime(28133):    at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:212)
10-27 11:39:14.311: E/AndroidRuntime(28133):    at com.example.sinhala.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
10-27 11:39:14.311: E/AndroidRuntime(28133):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
10-27 11:39:14.311: E/AndroidRuntime(28133):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
10-27 11:39:14.311: E/AndroidRuntime(28133):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
10-27 11:39:14.311: E/AndroidRuntime(28133):    ... 11 more
```

What could possibly be the reason for this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Here you have an efficent way to change the font for the entire application: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847531/access-a-typeface-once-from-asset-and-use-it-as-a-reference/18847778#18847778

Comment: I tired that answer, it throws out an exception: native typeface cannot be made. What needs to be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you created a folder called `fonts` in assets or directly placed in `assets` folder??if folder not created create a folder and place your font file there I think that is the mistake..In your example he is not created any `fonts` folder he is directly accessing but you are accessing from fonts folder..

If not fonts folder then change this line to.

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/amal.TTF");
```

like this..

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "amal.TTF");
```

Answer (score 4):

i got the same exception.
in my case i gave a wrong path to my ttf file.
i wrote: `/font/somefont.ttf`
i fixed it by removing the first hyphen: `font/somefont.ttf`

Answer (score 3):

You'll save yourself a lot of trouble, if you're using Android Studio, by placing the "assets/" folder WITHIN "src/main", NOT on the same level as "src/".

Comment: Thx, this solution worked for me! ${project_root}\app\src\main\assets\font.ttf

Answer (score 1):

In `Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/amal.TTF");` change to

`Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/amal.ttf");`
that solved for me.