# Try using own Font in Application throws error

Tags: android, fonts

i'm trying to set a custom Font to all of my TextViews/EditViews and so on. And i followed this answere: [Is it possible to set a custom font for entire of application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-font-for-entire-application/16883281#16883281)

For this i have a `.ttf` file in `assets/Fonts/myFont.ttf`. To add this `Font` to all of my `TextViews` i'm overriding the `TextView-Class`:

```
public class MyCustomTextView extends TextView {

public MyCustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public MyCustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public MyCustomTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                                           "myFont.ttf");
    setTypeface(tf);
}
```

}

To add this to my TextView i simply do in the layout:

```
 <com.android.faccess.MyCustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    style="@style/textview" />
```

Where the Style is:

```
<style name="textview">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">28dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal|center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">5dp</item>
```

**The Error**

I think i do miss something really simple. This is the LogCat:

`12-17 10:16:21.633: E/AndroidRuntime(2094): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.android.faccess.MyCustomTextView
12-17 10:16:21.633: E/AndroidRuntime(2094): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
12-17 10:16:21.633: E/AndroidRuntime(2094):     at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:175)
12-17 10:16:21.633: E/AndroidRuntime(2094):     at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:149)
12-17 10:16:21.633: E/AndroidRuntime(2094):     at com.android.faccess.MyCustomTextView.init(MyCustomTextView.java:28)
12-17 10:16:21.633: E/AndroidRuntime(2094):     at com.android.faccess.MyCustomTextView.<init>(MyCustomTextView.java:18)
12-17 10:16:21.633: E/AndroidRuntime(2094):     ... 51 more`

I'm developing for Android 4.0 and above so no Need to worry about leaks with this solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try this answer, may be this is your problem.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615217/changing-font-in-android-app-crashes-the-application-native-typeface-cannot-be

Comment: @RemeesMSyde That worked ! Nice. Post it as an answere and i will mark as accepted ! Thank you!

Comment: Answer is there dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you created a folder called fonts in assets or directly placed in assets folder??if folder not created create a folder and place your font file there
.
**If no fonts folder use the path like this.**

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "myfont.TTF");
```

**else**

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/myfont.TTF");
```

For more info try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615217/changing-font-in-android-app-crashes-the-application-native-typeface-cannot-be)