# Corona SDK custom font appearing small

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I added a custom font to a newEmbossedText, however when i view it in game, it appears tiny even though the font-size argument is 60.

```
  local scoreText = display.newEmbossedText(group, currentScore, 0, 0, "Infinium-Guardian", 60);
```

Comment: What resolution are you runnning at? Have you tried doubling the size to 120 to see if it registers correctly? There is nothing wrong in the code you provided.

Comment: no matter how much i change the size it stays miniscule

Comment: Try `scoreText.size = 60` and/or `scoreText:setSize(60)`, if that does not work then you must include more code for us to help.

Comment: The font is included in build settings as UIAppFonts, is there an alternate way to achieve this effect?

Comment: Try not using EmbossedText (i.e, use just display.newText) to see if it is a bug related to the embossed function.

Also, the way that you are using to call the function is deprecated. You should pass a table as argument (See more here: http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newEmbossedText.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For displaying custom font in Corona Simulator, you have to install the font in your system, and get the correct name of the font. When I tried with the same font, the font name string was:

```
"Infinium Guardian"
```

So, try changing your code as below, and check again:

```
local scoreText = display.newEmbossedText("Test String", 0, 0, "Infinium Guardian", 100);
```

[image]

Hope this could solve your issue.

For more information about integrating custom-fonts in your corona app, you can refer my answer on the post: [How do you integrate custom fonts in an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681054/how-do-you-integrate-custom-fonts-in-an-app/19688781#19688781)

Keep coding .................. :)