# Font issue in Corona SDK

Tags: android, fonts, lua, coronasdk

I am working on an Android Application on Corona Sdk.
and I am using chinacat font for it.
The Problem is the font is being displayed correctly in simulator,
but when i deploy on device it is displayed in normal font.
I am on Windows 8.1.

### Here is my code:

### local fontname="chinacat"

### texts = display.newText(word, 0, 0, fontname, fontsize)

~Thanks

Comment: Have you included the font file in the apk?

Comment: No, I Didn't.How to do that???

Comment: Just put the file in the main project folder (with the main.lua)

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681054/how-do-you-integrate-custom-fonts-in-an-app/19688781#19688781

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Custom Fonts can be tricky at first, specially regarding what name to use as the font filename as well as inside the code.

Just follow the guide below and you will be fine.

http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2013/01/16/faq-wednesday-custom-fonts/

Answer (score 1):

Just put it in the root folder of your project. And make sure that the font supports from a-z,A-z,0-9 if the font doesn't support it, your app will use the native font