# Customizing the fonts?

Tags: android-fragments

How to customize the ttf fonts on tab fragments? I am using sherlockactionbar.
Here is my code,

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/ptr_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>
```

And in Main activity am using,

```java
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /** to check whether user logged in or not */
    session = new TwitterHomeActivity(getApplicationContext());
    session.checklogin();

    /** Getting a reference to action bar of this activity */
    mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);

    /** Set tab navigation mode */
    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    /** Getting a reference to ViewPager from the layout */
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    /** Getting a reference to FragmentManager */
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    /** Defining a listener for pageChange */
    ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            setTitle(getTitleFromPosition(position));
            mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            // mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_chance_icon);
        }

        private CharSequence getTitleFromPosition(int position) {
            if (position == 0) {
                title = "text";
            } else if (position == 1) {
                title = "text";
            } else if (position == 2) {
                title = "text";
            } else if (position == 3) {
                title = "text";
            }
            return title;
        }
    };

    /** Setting the pageChange listner to the viewPager */
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);

    /** Creating an instance of FragmentPagerAdapter */
    MyFragmentPagerAdapter fragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(
            fm);

    /** Setting the FragmentPagerAdapter object to the viewPager object */
    mPager.setAdapter(fragmentPagerAdapter);

    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    /** Defining tab listener */
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

            mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }
    };

    /**/

    Tab tab = mActionBar.newTab();
    tab = mActionBar.newTab();

    tab.setText(“text”);

    tab.setTabListener(tabListener);

    mActionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = mActionBar.newTab();
    tab.setText(“ttext”);
    tab.setTabListener(tabListener);

    mActionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = mActionBar.newTab();
    tab.setText(“text”);
    tab.setTabListener(tabListener);

    mActionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = mActionBar.newTab();

    tab.setText(“text”);
    tab.setTabListener(tabListener);

    mActionBar.addTab(tab);

    try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class
                .getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if (menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Ignore
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.camera:
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Request_Broadcast.class));
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in,
                R.anim.right_slide_out);
        return true;

    case R.id.find_people:
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Find_people.class));
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in,
                R.anim.right_slide_out);
        return true;
    case R.id.action_settings:
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pro_settings.class));
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in,
                R.anim.right_slide_out);
        return true;

    }
    return true;
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void setActionBarTitle(int feedPage) {
    getActionBar().setTitle(feedPage);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {

}
```

}

Now i want to customize the fonts on tab using typeface. How to do that and the text on tabs is displaying in uppercase letters. I want to display that in lowercase letters..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an efficent way to change the font for the entire application: [Access a typeface once from asset and use it as a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847531/access-a-typeface-once-from-asset-and-use-it-as-a-reference/18847778#18847778)

**EDIT**

---

You can use the source code of the class I refer you to the link above. Now what you can do is change the font recursively starting from the parent layout and descending for each of their children. You should be aware that any view that can contain text is directly or indirectly a subclass of the TextView class (ie Button, EditText, CheckBox, CompoundButton, RadioButton, ToggleButton, etc). If you want to use different fonts in your application you can use for example the tag property of the view to define the font that will have that particular view. An example layout would look like this:

activity_main.xml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tag="title"
    android:text="This is the title screen" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tag="content"
    android:text="This is the activity content." />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tag="content"
    android:text="This is a button" />
```

Below this is the recursive method through which you can change the font of all views of the activity. This method is an additional method defined in class **[FontUtils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847531/access-a-typeface-once-from-asset-and-use-it-as-a-reference/18847778#18847778)**:

public static void setActivityTypeFace(Context context, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

```
Object tagAux;

for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {

    View viewChild = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);

    if (viewChild instanceof ViewGroup) {
        setActivityTypeFace(context, (ViewGroup) viewChild);

    } else if (viewChild instanceof TextView) {

        tagAux = viewChild.getTag();

        if (tagAux != null) {

            if (((String) tagAux).compareTo("title") == 0) 
            {
                ((TextView) viewChild).setTypeface(getTypeface(context,
                        FontType.TITLE_FONT.toString()));
            }
        } else if (((String) tagAux).compareTo("content") == 0) {
            ((TextView) viewChild).setTypeface(getTypeface(context,
                    FontType.CONTENT_FONT.toString()));
        }
    }
}
```

}

**MainActivity.java**

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity

        private ViewGroup mRootView;

        ...

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                mRootView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.rootView);
                ...
                FontUtil.setActivityTypeFace(this, mRootView);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not using textview. Am using sherlockactionbar fragments. Its not working.

Comment: Please check the edition I just did. If you think the answer was helpful for you please mark as correct answer to close the thread :)