# RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made

Tags: android, fonts

I'm trying to use a custom font on elements of a listview. So in my ListViewAdapter constructor I have:

```
private Context context;
private List<Project> projects;
private Typeface tf;
public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Project> projects) {
    super(context, resource, projects);
    this.context = context;
    this.projects = projects;
    tf = getTypefaceForListItems();
}

public Typeface getTypefaceForListItems()
{
    return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
}
```

In getView method I apply this typeface to a textview. The problem is that I get a Runtime exception: native typeface cannot be made and I don't understand what seems to be the problem.

Here's the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
            at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:175)
            at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:149)
            at com.maxcode.clientcheck.ProjectListAdapter.getTypefaceForListItems(ProjectListAdapter.java:41)
            at com.maxcode.clientcheck.ProjectListAdapter.<init>(ProjectListAdapter.java:25)
            at com.maxcode.clientcheck.ProjectListActivity$GetProjectsAsyncTask.onPostExecute(ProjectListActivity.java:154)
            at com.maxcode.clientcheck.ProjectListActivity$GetProjectsAsyncTask.onPostExecute(ProjectListActivity.java:91)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Also I wanted to mention that all my fonts are in src/main/assests/fonts folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Native typeface cannot be made" only for some people](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766930/native-typeface-cannot-be-made-only-for-some-people)

Comment: (also please google your exception before asking a new question, or, if you don't find your answer in the previously asked questions, indicate all that you have tried.)

Comment: I've tried the solution indicated in the link - but the exception persists. I've also googled for an answer but no luck - that's why I've posted this question! ;)

Comment: I understand your position. But as long as you don't indicate what you have attempted so far, what i can only see is that the question is very similar to the one I indicated and a dozen others, and therefore the answer should be the same as well.

Answer (score 12):

One problem that's overlooked (by Android Studio users) is that the "assets/" folder is NOT on the same level as "src/". It is INSIDE "src/main/"

Because I didn't see this earlier, I spent two hours last night, and an hour this morning just trying to change the font in my navigation drawer.

I believe this is the same reason why pixlUI and calligraphy libraries did not work for me.

Comment: @Fakher delive What version of AS are you using? This works on the current version (2.1)

Answer (score 0):

I do my fonts like this: (I declare them in my MainActivity)

```
public static TypeFace FONT_HEADINGS;
```

Then I set them up in onCreate()

```
FONT_HEADINGS = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "MyriadPro-Cond.otf");
```

At this point, I can reference them throughout my app as:

```
sampleTextView.setTypeFace(MainActivity.FONT_HEADINGS);
```

Edit:

"src/main/assests/fonts"

the "assets" folder should not be under the "src" folder. It belongs in the at the same level as the src, res, etc.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem because - the name and extension of the font are how I've added them in my code: OpenSans-Regular.ttf Thanks!

Comment: Great - this could work too...but the problem for me seems to be that when calling Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "MyriadPro-Cond.otf"); I get a RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made - and the cause seems to be that getAssets returns null ... because when I call ex.getCause() in the catch clause it said simply...null.

Comment: From what I understand - because Android Studio started using the Gradle build system - the assets folder should be under the "src/main" folder. -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-to-place-assets-folder-in-android-studio

Comment: Was unaware you werent using ADT in Eclipse.

Comment: Isn't android studio in Beta? Id avoid it until its stable. Less headaches.

Comment: :)) In this case I can't avoid it! I guess I have to find a solution for this and still using Android Studio

Comment: Lol, just  checking because in your question it says "assests" :)

Comment: @William Better Create all your TypeFace objects in Application class as in most cases we have to use same typeface through out the project and its will consume high memory if we create it in each activity. Or correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score -1):

OpenSans-Regular.ttf  should be under fonts folder .

folder structure should be like this :

assets-> fonts ->OpenSans-Regular.ttf

```
i think by mistake you have added under assets folder
```