# Native Typeface Cannot be Made for 4.0.3-4.0.4

Tags: android

I just launched an app to the app store and am getting errors from people about inflating my custom TextView, which I use to implement a custom font. The errors seem to come from people running 4.0.3 or 4.0.4, and it works fine on my S3 running 4.3 as well as a Nexus 7. Is there something I'm missing to make this compatible? I'm aware of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766930/native-typeface-cannot-be-made-only-for-some-people) which has the same problem but doesn't quite solve it. I added a try/catch to have it default back to the built-in font but it seems like there should be a solution for this so I can use my custom fonts.

Logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:430)
at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:404)
at com.gtf.oneparish.AvTextView.<init>(AvTextView.java:18)
... 25 more
```

AvTextView:

```
public class AvTextView extends TextView {
    public static Typeface FONT_NAME;


    public AvTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        try {
            if(FONT_NAME == null) FONT_NAME = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/avenirlight.ttf");
            this.setTypeface(FONT_NAME);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Font Creation error", "Could not get typeface because " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public AvTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        try {
            if(FONT_NAME == null) FONT_NAME = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/avenirlight.ttf");
            this.setTypeface(FONT_NAME);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Font Creation error", "Could not get typeface because " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public AvTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        try {
            if(FONT_NAME == null) FONT_NAME = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/avenirlight.ttf");
            this.setTypeface(FONT_NAME);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Font Creation error", "Could not get typeface because " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems Android 4.0.x is a bit picky with fonts and refuses to load some of them for whatever reason. I was able to get my custom font to load by tweaking its font info in FontForge (to more closely match another font that does load successfully) and generating a new .ttf file. The original .ttf works fine on my computer and with Androids 2.3.x, 4.3, and 4.4, but throws an exception in 4.0.3 and 4.0.4.