# custom font in Android Studio

Tags: android, fonts, android-typeface

How to create custom fonts in android studio ?
Im trying to use a custom font, and I've read that I suppose to place the fonts in assets/fonts.
I have searched long and hard but found nothing that helped yet.
Where I wrong? I really do not know what to do.
I wrote all the details below. I've tried and did not succeed.
I'm using Android Studio and it doesn't seem like I have a assets folder. So I created one. But my app crashes when I place the assets folder in /main/assets. Im using this code to load my fonts.

I know that . structure for a project in Android Studio 0.5.2:

```
root-module
|--.idea
|--app
|----build
|----src
|------main
|--------assets
|----------fonts/SomeFont.ttc
|----------fonts/AnotherFont.otf
|--------java
|----------source code here
|--------res
|------AndroidManifest.xml
|----build.gradle
```

***Update***

my fonte file dir : E:\AndroidProjects\ReadNews\ReadNews\src\main\assets\fonts\

***end Update***

my code :

```
 @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
            TextView titleTextView = (TextView) _dialog.findViewById(R.id.title_news_TextView);
            TextView messageTextView = (TextView) _dialog.findViewById(R.id.message_TextView);
            String fontPath = "fonts/Tahoma.ttf";
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(MainActivity.this.getResources().getAssets(), fontPath);
            titleTextView.setTypeface(tf);
            messageTextView.setTypeface(tf);
        }
```

error :

> 06-27 07:40:37.985    4206-4206/com.mmd2009.readnews E/AndroidRuntime﹕
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.mmd2009.readnews, PID: 4206
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: **native typeface cannot be made**
>               at android.graphics.Typeface.(Typeface.java:175)
>               at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:149)
>               at com.mmd2009.readnews.MainActivity$ReadNewsAsyncTask.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:216)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
>               at com.mmd2009.readnews.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:70)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

my ReadNews-ReadNews.iml :

```
  <facet type="android" name="Android">
      <configuration>
        <option name="SELECTED_BUILD_VARIANT" value="debug" />
        <option name="ASSEMBLE_TASK_NAME" value="assembleDebug" />
        <option name="COMPILE_JAVA_TASK_NAME" value="compileDebugJava" />
        <option name="ASSEMBLE_TEST_TASK_NAME" value="assembleDebugTest" />
        <option name="SOURCE_GEN_TASK_NAME" value="generateDebugSources" />
        <option name="ALLOW_USER_CONFIGURATION" value="false" />
        <option name="MANIFEST_FILE_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" />
        <option name="RES_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/src/main/res" />
        <option name="RES_FOLDERS_RELATIVE_PATH" value="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res" />
        <option name="ASSETS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/src/main/assets" />
      </configuration>
    </facet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your font path is incorrect. You have no `font`folder.  Change your font path to just `"Tahoma.ttf"`, or create the folder inside of your asset folder.

**EDIT**

This appears to be a bug that happens with Android OS on occasion.  Check out this link, it appears it has been addressed already. ["Native typeface cannot be made" only for some people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766930/native-typeface-cannot-be-made-only-for-some-people)

Comment: i have a font folder. The structure above was just an example.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you are referring to a font file that does not exist. Your directory listing does not show `fonts/Tahoma.ttf`, which is what your code is referring to.

Beyond that, it may be that Android simply does not like your font file for some reason. Try a different font file.

Comment: i use different font file But my app crashes. my fonte file is "arial.ttf"

Comment: @user3763877: Your path was `fonts/Tahoma.ttf`. Not only was there no `Tahoma.ttf` file, there is no `fonts/` directory inside of `assets/`.

Comment: i have a font folder. The structure above was just an example. my fonte file dir : E:\AndroidProjects\ReadNews\ReadNews\src\main\assets\fonts\