# Android setTypeface not working correctly

Tags: android, android-activity

i writing simple new application in android and i want to using setTypeface to  Activity widgets.

in this below code It seems thats correct but i get this error in console:

```
1803-1803/com.example.AndroidMultiPage E/AndroidRuntime﹕ 
     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
    ComponentInfo{com.example.AndroidMultiPage/
    com.example.AndroidMultiPage.MyActivity}: 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: 

    native typeface cannot be made
```

Font path: `assets/font/BZar.ttf`

My Simple code:

```
package com.example.AndroidMultiPage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private Button submit;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "font/BZar.ttf");

        Button   submit   = (Button)   findViewById(R.id.submitButton);

        submit.setTypeface(face);

}
```

Comment: Try a different font. For whatever reason, not all fonts are compatible with Android.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766930/native-typeface-cannot-be-made-only-for-some-people

Answer (score 2):

```
public void setFont(Context context, ViewGroup vg, String fontInAssetFolder) {
    final Typeface font=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontInAssetFolder);
    for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
        final View v = vg.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup)
            setFont(context, (ViewGroup) v, fontInAssetFolder);
        else if (v instanceof TextView) {
            Log.e("FONT", "IS = "+ font.toString()+ "; is " + ((TextView)v).getText());
            v.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    (((TextView) v)).setTypeface(font);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping the typeface file in asset folder and also try using different font file.

Answer (score 0):

It's because it's 'fonts' (plural) not 'font'.

You have 'assets/font/your_font' and it should be 'assets/fonts/your_font'.
Rename the folder and update the code.