# In Android How to set Text?

Tags: java, android, maven

I am developing my app with Maven build tool..
In my **assets** folder I have fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf..

And my **activity_main.xml** is:--

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bck54"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="99dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
        android:text="hello world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my **HelloAndroidActivity.java** is:--

```
public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf");
         tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         tv.setTypeface(tf);

    }


}
```

Here I want to change my text fonts..But the app is stopped..
My logcat error is:--

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.arijit.patra.love/com.arijit.patra.love.HelloAndroidActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2346)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2398)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:159)
```

Can anyone tell me where is the problem??

Comment: tv.setText("YOUR TEXT");

Comment: I have added..But still its not working

Comment: Did you add your font `DroidSansFallback` in fonts folder under assets?

Comment: where is your font stored in your project?

Comment: @ Giru Bhai  yes my dear..In my ques I have already said that..its under asstes/fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf

Comment: visit this tutorial... http://stand2code.blogspot.in/2014/06/using-custom-fonts.html

Comment: @SomChatterjee,where assert directory located in your project ? and nothing going wrong in your code might be some problem assert directory structure.

Comment: Please understand your log "native typeface cannot be made", and search  for solution. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766930/native-typeface-cannot-be-made-only-for-some-people)  is workaround for it.

Comment: add another tff file and run if works its confirm that ur current tff file is currepted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be your font file is corrupted that's why you get this error message.
delete that file and download again from somewhere else and put it again in your asset folder.

Comment: Thnx..Now its working..is there any other way where I can change the fonts xml..I mean 2 say not in run time..In run time there is a problem to set the texts..is there any other way?

Comment: for that you need to make your Custom textView then you can change font in xml. and note that when you add your custom textView in xml at that time you can not see the font change reflaction , it shown only at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you created a folder called fonts in assets or directly placed in assets folder??if folder not created create a folder and place your font file there I think that is the mistake..In your example he is not created any fonts folder he is directly accessing but you are accessing from fonts folder..

If not fonts folder then change this line to.

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/amal.TTF");
```

like this..

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "amal.TTF");
```

it its not working than,

The font file is either corrupt or unsupported for some reason.