# FontType in a Splash Screen

Tags: android, android-typeface

i'm trying to change the font family on my splash screen.

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


/** Duration of wait **/
private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 1000;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity
     * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, ApresentationActivity.class);
            SplashActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            SplashActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);


}
```

I already tried to use typeFace, but without success.
Can i use typeface without using savedInstanceState?

`TextView myTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textBox);
Typeface typeFace=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/mytruetypefont.ttf");
myTextView.setTypeface(typeFace);`

EDIT 1:

```
package com.example.jelbez.json;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.Html;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView txtTitle;

/** Duration of wait **/
private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 1000;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity
     * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, ApresentationActivity.class);
            SplashActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            SplashActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);


    TextView myTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    Typeface typeFace=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/mytruetypefont.ttf");
    myTextView.setTypeface(typeFace);
}



}
```

This is not working, it returns me Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made

Comment: your code seems ok, can you post the Activity with what you've tried and the XML of the Layout?

Comment: Did you read this question, it might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766930/native-typeface-cannot-be-made-only-for-some-people

Comment: it worked for me, thanks a lot.

Comment: @JosefElBez where you have keep your `mytruetypefont.ttf` file ?

Answer (score 0):

you should to write textview and typeface before handler like this

```
TextView myTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
Typeface typeFace= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/mytruetypefont.ttf");
myTextView.setTypeface(typeFace);

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, ApresentationActivity.class);
        SplashActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
        SplashActivity.this.finish();
    }
}, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
```

if not work check your fonts folder in assets
again if not work, change onCreate and use this

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 1000;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

TextView myTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/mytruetypefont.ttf");
myTextView.setTypeface(typeFace);

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, ApresentationActivity.class);
        SplashActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
        SplashActivity.this.finish();
    }
}, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
}
```