# How to use custom font in android library project?

Tags: android, android-library

I have created a TextView library project where I have used a custom font. I have to create this library because this `TextView` will use in other three project as well. I found that assets/fonts folder is not supported by android library project. If I use this way it gives me error message

```
native typeface cannot be made at android.graphics.Typeface
```

Is there any workaround here to solve this issue. Other way, I have to use duplicate view in three different app. And also the sample code I am using to get font from library assets folder.

```
 public static Typeface getFont(Context c, String fontName) {
        synchronized (fonts) {
            if (!fonts.containsKey(fontName)) {
                Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(
                        c.getAssets(), "fonts" + File.separator + fontName);
                fonts.put(fontName, t);
            }
            return fonts.get(fontName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you share code ? which are you using?

Comment: create `assets/fonts` folder in your library

Comment: What build system are you using?

Comment: gradle @MuhammadBabar

Comment: link your assets inside your gradle like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18170916/1939564

Comment: are you sure? You have font name with it's extension also. if not then change your one line of code.  Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(
                        c.getAssets(), "fonts" + File.separator + fontName+ ".ttf");

Answer (score 0):

infect you can do lot of things .one of easiest solution is following

you can write a function that copy paste font in some sd card folder and for sure it will be static . now you can create type from that path

```
createFromFile(String path)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html

Answer (score 0):

To use different Fonts in my project I have use font Library. Just add this library in gradle.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.vstechlab.easyfonts:easyfonts:1.0.0'
}
```

Use of this library is very easy. I have use reference https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2044

Answer (score -1):

create fonts directory in your assets folder and set your font with ttf format in the font directory. then call font by this code:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/font.ttf");
textViewName.setTypeface(tf);
```

your font must be here :

> assets>fonts>font.ttf

Comment: You must create assets folder inside src-->main in AndroidStudio. This way works for me!

Comment: Did you use this solution in android library project? I am discussing about the Library project not the application project.