# NDK Assets between projects

Tags: android-ndk

I have a library project, which includes the sharedobjs (NDK) and the JNI code - and some assets.
This is included into an application project, with the actual Java app.

I've read that you can use the AssetManager to access them.
But just wondering, would this mess-up because of the multiple projects?

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889833/android-library-assets-folder-doesnt-get-copied