# Android wear assets and libs dir

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

I have working app in Android Studio (gradle) that have assets DIR where I keep my graphics and etc... I have created a wearable app that works but I have the same assets , libs ,etc that I have in my main app. In other words, I have the same files copied in assets and libs dir in both my main app and my wearable app.

How can I avoid this and make my wearable app use the same assets and libs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a library module separate from either (wearable or handheld) app, and put the common assets and libs in there. Let's call that module `commonLibrary`. Then you set both apps up to reference it. So in both apps' `build.gradle` file, include the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':commonLibrary')
    // other dependencies go in here as well
}
```

For more information on library modules, see http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryModules

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. But there is a problem. From the documentation you provided :Library modules cannot include raw assets
The tools do not support the use of raw asset files (saved in the assets/ directory) in a library module. Any asset resources used by an application must be stored in the assets/ directory of the application module itself. However, resource files saved in the res/ directory are supported.  - So I can`t make the commonLib to have assets ?

Comment: That documentation is out of date. Assets couldn't be included in library projects with Eclipse, but using Gradle, they can: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6527926/252080

Comment: Ok. I`l follow this. Cheers