# Assets in assets/ directory for Android library (aar)

Tags: android, assets, android-library, aar

Based on [Android Library Considerations](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#Considerations):

> Library modules cannot include raw assets

I created a sample android library module with assets in there (not in app module), then generated the aar file. I analyzed the resulting aar file, and voila, the assets/ folder is still there with all the files intact.

So, is it allowed or not allowed?

Comment: I think you can,I have seen it in many projects!

Comment: `Can I confidently distribute my aar file to my clients?` Are you distributing the `aar` file *separately*, or **always** bundled with the app (merged `res` and `assets`)?

Comment: i want to distribute it to my clients, so my clients can use my aar file in their own app.

Comment: have you obfuscated? Please do verify, as in reverse engineering of apk anyone can see files inside assets.

Comment: obfuscation is my next step. as of now, i want to get an answer to the question i posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that some of the *Development considerations* are outdated. For example they also says that `<uses-library>` elements must be declared in both the library and the application (this is now handled by the manifest merger).

By the way a few lines below, *Anatomy of an AAR file* shows that an AAR file may include an `/assets/` directory

Answer (score 4):

I raised this *document problem* in [Android Library Considerations:](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#Considerations) with `Google` on `May 7, 2018` [issuetracker 79311037](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79311037).

It is being dealt with, here's the latest comment (`Jul 14, 2018`):

> As well as being wrong, the documentation also contradicts itself, as
>   the "Anatomy of an AAR file" section at the bottom *does* include an
>   assets directory.

Answer (score 3):

Folder assets/ is not allowed in android library. you can access it from res/raw
with following code.

```
context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file_name);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some interesting posts on the subject:

[how to reference an asset in a library project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346889/how-to-reference-an-asset-in-a-library-project)

[Android Library assets folder doesn't get copied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889833/android-library-assets-folder-doesnt-get-copied)

All it says is that: **Library modules cannot include raw assets**
it does not say **Library modules should not include raw assets** . Maybe in the past it was not supported. Now as the above posts and their answers indicate it is supported.